# Canceling an Async thread from within the thread itself

Tags: multithreading, haskell, asynchronous, cancellation

Is there a way to use `cancel` from within a thread invoked with `async` from the [async](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) package? I can see that you can cancel it from outside the thread, but I'm wondering if there could be a `cancelSelf :: IO ()` function which stops its own execution. I *could* staple something together with unique id generation and a shared `Map` of `Async` thread references, which the thread itself could reference, but that just seems too much. Could I get away with an uncaught exception or something?

Comment: It seems to me that since your proposed `cancelSelf` function needs you to be in IO at the point at which you'd want to cancel, it would be equally easy to be in `EitherT String IO` instead, and just "cancel" by returning `Left "cancelled"` or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An async action can cancel itself.  It involves a bit of a trick, though.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}

import Control.Concurrent.Async

main :: IO ()
main = do
    rec let doCancel = cancel calculate
        calculate <- async doCancel
    wait calculate
```

In theory, you can do that without `RecursiveDo`, but I've never wanted to write an [`mfix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Fix.html#v:mfix) expression (what `RecursiveDo` bindings desugar to) by hand.

`RecursiveDo` allows you to create a mutually-recursive set of definitions inside a do block, even if some of the definitions are bound with `<-` and some are defined inside a `let` statement.  As always, if there is a real circularity involved, the calculation will diverge.  But there are lots of cases where all you want to do is be able to refer to the name of something else like the example above, and `RecursiveDo` works just fine.

Oh, and [the implementation of `mfix` for `IO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/System.IO.html#fixIO) is terrifying. I'm glad I didn't have to write it myself.

-- Edit --

Since this has received almost no feedback, I've realized it's not completely obvious how to use this in order to solve your problem.  So here's an expanded example that uses a combinator to spawn an `Async` that can cancel itself:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}

-- obviously want the async library
import Control.Concurrent.Async

-- used in selfCancelableAsync
import Control.Monad      (forever)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

-- only used for demonstration
import System.Random      (randomIO)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    a <- selfCancelableAsync $ \selfCancel -> do
        choice <- randomIO
        if choice then return "Success!" else selfCancel
    result <- wait a
    putStrLn result

-- spawns an Async that has the ability to cancel itself by
-- using the action passed to the IO action it's running
selfCancelableAsync :: (IO a -> IO b) -> IO (Async b)
selfCancelableAsync withCancel = do
    rec let doCancel = do
                cancel calculate
                -- This must never return to ensure it has the correct type.
                -- It uses threadDelay to ensure it's not hogging resources
                -- if it takes a moment to get killed.
                forever $ threadDelay 1000

        calculate <- async $ withCancel doCancel

    return calculate
```

Comment: "`mfix f` executes the action `f` only once, with the eventual output fed back as the input. Hence `f` should not be strict, for then `mfix f` would diverge". Yep, in a really bad way - it'll block on the `takeMVar`.